# new project Eclipse, Dynamic web module error

Tags: eclipse

I'm new in the Eclipse world, but when I want to create my first project in Eclipse I got this message when I select Java Server Faces Facet:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyot4.png)

Can anybody help me?

Should I miss something? I'm working with OpenJDK 8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[image] change Dynamic web Module to 2.5 or you can lower the JSF to a lower verion